# Linking third party domain to amazon elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk environment running at http://environmentname.eba-xca8mcpp.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/ and I wish to has the domain name http://www.mywebsite.org (registered with namecheap) direct to this.

I have set up a route 53 hosted zone with two type A records routing traffic from mywebsite.org and [www.mywebsite.org](http://www.mywebsite.org) to environmentname.eba-xca8mcpp.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com. I also have NS and SOA records their.

On the namecheap side I have a CNAME record  with a 'www ' host and a value of 'environmentname.eba-xca8mcpp.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com.' I also have a URL redirect record with a '@' host and a value of 'http://www.mywebsite.org'. I also have NS record with 'www' hosts with values of the ns addressed shown on the route 53 page.

When I visit mywebsite.org however I receive a 'This site can't be reached' message. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot in this case?

Answer (score 0):

On the namecheap side I also needed to add 'A Record' with both a 'www' and '@' as host and for the values it was the IP address (obtained via https://www.whatismyip.com/dns-lookup/) for  http://environmentname.eba-xca8mcpp.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/